# How can I generate batch of coordinates from linestring to simulate driving on map?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a openlayers map and I want to simulate driving a route on it.
I would like to draw a line (using GPX tool) and create gps coordinates (preferred with advancing time stamp) so I can query them based on time and show on the map the advancement.

what is the easiest way doing this interpolation ? I have PostGIS and QGIS (or other tool !?) but I'm not familiar with python programming for QGIS.

Comment: I don't know much about the GPX tool. You could generate a series of time stamps and points along a line using [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html), the Postgres Interval function and generate_series, ie, directly in Postgres/Postgis. If this will work for you, I will post the query.

Comment: This sounds good but I have no idea how to execute it.
Can you write example query and I'll run it on my route?

Comment: @JohnBarça - The ST_Line_Interpolate_Point gets a float which declare a precentage on the line to create a point , so if I want exact interval - like each 100m for example , I need to calculate the float ? 

Will be more than happy to get an example query :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach would be using [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html), in conjunction with the [timestamp + INTERVAL interval type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html) construct, using [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-srf.html) to calculate the time steps and fractions along a line, eg.,

```
WITH start AS 
  (SELECT 
       ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)') as geom, 
       '2015-03-12 10:00:00'::timestamp as start_time), 
intervals as 
  (SELECT 
      generate_series (0, 10) as steps)
  SELECT  
     start_time + INTERVAL '1 MINUTES' * steps AS ts,
     ST_AsText(ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 
  FROM intervals))) AS geom
FROM start, intervals;
```

returns

```
     ts             |  geom   
--------------------+--------------
2015-03-12 10:00:00 | POINT(0 0)
2015-03-12 10:01:00 | POINT(1 1)
2015-03-12 10:02:00 | POINT(2 2)
.................................. etc
2015-03-12 10:10:00 | POINT(10 10)
```

You could just as easily use `now() + INTERVAL '1 HOURS'` (or seconds, minutes, days) instead of a timestamp. Note the use of INTERVAL '1 MINUTES' * some_number to do the steps. Also, when you divide the steps by the step number, to get the  fraction between 0 and 1 along you line, you need to cast to float, or else you will get integer division. Or just replace `(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 
  FROM intervals)` with 10.0, but it is more dynamic to get the count directly in this way, and so you can change 10 to any number of intervals you like along the line, without worrying about magic numbers.

You will want to remove the `ST_AsText` from the above -- I left it in so you could see the values and that the interpolate is working correctly.

Clearly, you will need to replace the linestring above with your actual data, and it does not have to be a straight line between two points as above, but I hope this gives you enough to go on. Someone else might come up with a nicer Python in QGIS approach -- I prefer doing everything in the DB, and using QGIS for visualization, but that is just personal preference.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you were thinking of

Comment: You sir are a genius , this is exactly what I needed and it worked like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

I have try to do something similar of what John says. But the problem for my data is that I have a lot of small roads (so, using ST_Line_Interpolate_Point for me its not so good, because on this little roads I get a lot of point if I use the percentage and no point If I calculate a certain distance) and I don't want to merge them (because I lose date in that case).

My suggest is to use [pgrouting](http://pgrouting.org/) and if you need the drivingtime maybe you can estimate it using the class of the street and the speed limit and make an update at the end of the process.

Comment: This would probably be better as a separate question, rather than as an answer to this one. It sounds like an interesting question.